# What does the phrase "laugh it up" mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english

I have come across it in the first episode of the sixth season of *Friends*. Here is the context:

> Rachel: Well, I guess we just find a divorce lawyer? (Looks at Ross.)
>
> Chandler: Well, I think, I think, Ross already has one. Now, this
>   one’s free, right? Because you paid for the first two, so the third
>   one’s free.
>
> Ross: **Laugh it up**, but the joke’s on you. Because we don’t need to get
>   divorced, okay? We we’re just gonna get an annulment.

I couldn't find any dictionary that gave the definition of *laught it up*. Is this some kind of non-standard American phrase? Could you tell me what it means and what is the synonymous phrase of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we follow a verb with *it up* in the sense used in **laugh it up**, it generally indicates that we are talking about doing something excessively, or putting on an act.

[**ham it up**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ham%20it%20up):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   *informal*
>   : to act or behave in an exaggerated or playful way
>   // She likes to *ham it up* for the camera.

[**camp it up**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/camp%20it%20up):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   *informal*
>   : to act with exaggerated speech or gestures
>   // He really *camped it up* on stage.

[**live it up**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/live):

> [Merriam-Webster, from *live*]
>   : to live with gusto and usually fast and loose
>   // *lived it up* with wine and song
>   — Newsweek

**Laugh it up**, in terms of its descriptive sense, has a similar exaggeration. It suggests a person laughing long and hard because they find something hilarious.

---

When used as an imperative (somebody being told to *laugh it up*), it's being used metaphorically and sarcastically.

Its meaning is similar to the following:

> Enjoy it while you can, because it won't last for long.
> (And soon you won't be laughing about it, because you'll see it's not actually funny, so get it out of your system now.)

---

I find it unusual that there seems to be no direct reference to this particular phrase, even though I'd say it has wide use and is commonly understood.

Answer (score 0):

To “laugh it up” loosely means to “share a laugh with a group of people”. In this context Ross’s first sentence could be interpreted as “you can continue joking about it but you don’t know all the details”.