# What does "hug it up" mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english, phrases

I have come across it in the 18th episode of the 6th season of *Friends*. Here is the context:

> Chandler: (To Joey) So, you busy Thursday?
>
> Joey: Oh, very funny. I don’t know if you remember, but my audition
>   was supposed to be Thursday. (Chandler doesn’t say anything until Joey
>   figures it out.) You got me the audition?! Let’s **hug it up**! (They
>   hug.)

Does it mean let's hug a lot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never heard *hug it up* before, but, from the context, it's a variation on the far more common [**hug it out**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/hug-it-out):

> [Macmillan Dictionary]
>   **to hug, especially to put an end to an argument or to show solidarity**
>   *We hugged it out and I thought that would be the end of it.*

Generally speaking, *hug it out* is more commonly used after an argument to express the fact that you're going to "hug and forget."

---

In this case, *hug it* ***up*** might have been used instead, because there hasn't been an actual conflict—and *up* is being used in a way similar to [*laugh it up*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/249024/73781), which was used in another *Friends* episode.